# Laravel Mail Can't Send

Tags: laravel

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "####@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted```

### i have got this error when sending mail.

My `.env` configaration is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=####@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=######
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure `.env`  like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after you make changes in your `.env` file.

> **NOTE:-**   you need to allow less secure apps from "Google Account" - https://myaccount.google.com/ - Settings - Less secure app access (Turn On)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, please try to enable less secure app.

Turn turn off 2 step verification and enable less secure app (as follows)

go to gmail.com
my account
and enable
Allow less secure apps: ON